# This dependency gives me two versions of one jar. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, jersey

I'm using Gradle for my project. One of the dependencies I have specified in my build.gradle is
 `compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.0'`

This works fine on a normal Java application, however when I try to build it on Android I get:

When looking at which libraries are referenced, it's clear that there's both `javax.inject-2.3.0-b05.jar` and `javax.inject-1.jar`, which I found are added by the dependency above. I'm guessing that this 'duplicate' jar is what causes the build error.

How do I go around this? Why does the dependency include two of the same jar? Is there a way to either make the Android version build with these two jars or to remove one of these jars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a dependency tree akin

```
project
|--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.0
| \--- *:javax.inject:1
\--- *:javax.inject:2.3.0-b05
```

Where * is the group, which I suspect may be different from those two.

Try getting an idea of how your dependencies are being grabbed by using the [dependency](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.DependencyReportTask.html) task

```
gradle dependency
```

Should you need to exclude a dependency enter it in the tag, similar to the below example

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate:3.1') {
  //excluding a particular transitive dependency:
  exclude module: 'cglib' //by artifact name
  exclude group: 'org.jmock' //by group
  exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'iAmBuggy' //by both name and group
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, the glassfish inject package has a dependency on inject 1: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2.external/javax.inject/2.5.0-b05

Answer (score 1):

Normally gradle will only include 1 jar per dependency. If different version found for the same depedencies, the newer version will be used.

However, in your case, these 2 jars are dependencies with different group names:

```
'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
'org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b05'
```

That's why gradle included both as they are treated as different dependencies.

'javax.inject:javax.inject:1' is very old, I think you should exclude it like what Niels Bech Nielsen said.

To find out where is this dependency come from , you can use command:

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency inject
```