# Cannot exclude module from Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use Jersey on Android by adding 
    `compile org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.16`
to my build.gradle file. It gives me an unexpected top-level exception, so I added `multiDexEnabled true` to it as well.

Now I get:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/inject/Qualifier.class

I figured out that Jersey is trying to import both `javax.inject:1` and `javax.inject:2.4.0-b09`. Okay no problem, we'll exclude the older one as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598961/this-dependency-gives-me-two-versions-of-one-jar-how-do-i-fix-this). So I tried:

```
compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.16') {
    exclude (module: 'javax.inject:1')
}
```

and

```
compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.16') {
    exclude (group: 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1')
}
```

But the module won't go away no matter what. I'm at the end of my rope here and have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Try `exclude group:'javax.inject', module:'javax.inject'`

Answer (score 0):

```
compile ('org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.16') {
   exclude (group:'javax.inject', module:'javax.inject')
}
```

Worked. Thanks [RaGe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745574/rage)!